# JMeter performance testing with concurrent users 100

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I want to test JMeter with 100 concurrent users and for 1 hour with 1 request in HTTP request.

**PFB configuration of JMeter.**

```
No of threads-100
rampup-1
loopcount fore ever
scheduler 
start time-2015/11/26 10:36:00
end time-2015/11/26 11:36:00
duration(secs)-3600
startup delay-0
```

Whether JMeter hit all 100 users in concurrent . or else I need to change any configuration.

PFA images for additional details.

[HTTP request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R33r0.jpg)

[image: Thread group details]

Comment: voting to close, unclear what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear in your question that what problem are you facing, So please be more specific.Let me guess about your problem.

**Concurrency** means "All the users are doing the **different activity** at the same time".

Do not get confused by the term between **"Concurrent users"** and **"Simultaneous Users"**.These two are not the **same**.

**Simulations users** mean all the users are doing the **same activity** at the same time.

To clear the concept about **"Concurrency"** and **"Simultaneity"** you should go through [this article](http://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/07/09/performance-testing-concepts-what-are-concurrent-users/).

So if you want to reach concurrency for those 100 users it will depend on your Test Scripts too.

In above test **100 Threads** will be concurrent when the **Ramp up time=1** second is reached.

If you want to monitor concurrent users at any given time, you should use [Active Threads Over Time](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener.